# Is it possible to combine several bootstrap classes into one?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using different bootstrap classes multiple times in an HTML `<form>`.
e.g.:

```html
<form id="frmData" name="frmData" method="POST">                    
    <div class="row justify-content-sm-center mb-2 align-items-center">         
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto d-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <label>....</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <input .....>
        </div>      
    </div>
    
    <div class="row justify-content-sm-center mb-2 align-items-center">         
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto d-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <label>....</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <input .....>
        </div>      
    </div>  
    
    ......
</form>
```

Is there an opportunity to define a `class` for the `<div>` of the `<label>` for example and reuse it for every `<div>` that is containing a label?
This would help a lot during development. Instead of changing the classes of each `<div>`, it would be sufficient to change only the class definition.

Something like this:

```
    <div class="div_class">
    <label>...</label>
    </div>

    <style>
        .div_class {
            .col-12 
            .col-sm-auto 
            .d-flex 
            .justify-content-md-end
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: In pure CSS - no. In preprocessors like Less or Sass - yes

Answer (score 0):

This I think will be the only way to do it in pure CSS. In this model all of the innner Div's and Label's should inherit settings from the new wrapper that I have added and `.div_class > *` ensures only children are affected not grandchildren. Give it a try any way.

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Now as many of your label divs as you need -->

    <div class="div_class">
        <label>...</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div_class">
        <label>...</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div_class">
        <label>...</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.wrapper * {
    color: black;

}
.div_class > * {
    color:blue;
}
```